Checking if entry exists in a SQL table or not in golang gives false everytime
This is my golang code. i am trying to check whether a user has applied to a job or not. If yes he should be displayed a message that you can't apply no more, if not it should successfully apply.
I have 3 tables in DB: User, Job, Job Application.
User has UserID as Primary Key,
Job has JobID as PK and Job Application has Application_ID as PK with 2 columns (JobID and UserID) as foreign Keys pointing to JobID in Job table and UserID in User table respectively.

func (d *Env) ApplyToJob(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    claims := r.Context().Value("claims").(jwt.MapClaims)
    if claims["is_admin"].(bool) {
        SendResponse(w, models.Response{Message: "Only Applicant Users can apply to this job!", Status: "Error"})
        return
    }
    uuid := claims["uuid"].(string)
    jobID := r.URL.Query().Get("job_id") // Extract job_id from query parameters
    if jobID == "" {
        SendResponse(w, models.Response{Message: "job_id parameter is required", Status: "Error"})
        return
    }
    //! Check if the job with jobID exists
    var jobExists bool
    err := d.Driver.QueryRow("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM job WHERE JobID = ?)", jobID).Scan(&jobExists)
    if err != nil {
        SendResponse(w, models.Response{Message: "Error checking job existence: " + err.Error(), Status: "Error"})
        return
    }
    if !jobExists {
        SendResponse(w, models.Response{Message: "Job does not exist", Status: "Error"})
        return
    }
    //! Check if the user (UUID) has already applied to this job (jobID)
    hasApplied, err := rowExists(d.Driver, "SELECT 1 FROM job_application WHERE JobID = ? AND UserID = ?", jobID, uuid)
    if err != nil {
        SendResponse(w, models.Response{Message: err.Error(), Status: "Error"})
        return
    } else {
        if hasApplied {
            SendResponse(w, models.Response{Message: "Already Applied to this Job!" + err.Error(), Status: "Error"})
            return
        } else {
            // ! Generating new applicationID
            applicationID, err := exec.Command("uuidgen").Output()
            if err != nil {
                response := models.Response{Message: err.Error(), Status: "Error"}
                SendResponse(w, response)
                return
            }
            _, err = d.Driver.Exec(`INSERT INTO 
job_application(ApplicationID, JobID,UserID,AppliedOn) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?)`,
                applicationID,
                jobID,
                uuid,
                time.Now(),
            )
            if err != nil {
                response := models.Response{Message: err.Error(), Status: "Error"}
                SendResponse(w, response)
                return
            }
            response := models.Response{Message: "Successfully Applied!", Status: "Success"}
            SendResponse(w, response)
        }
    }

}

func rowExists(db *sql.DB, query string, args ...interface{}) (bool, error) {
    var exists bool
    query = fmt.Sprintf("SELECT EXISTS (%s)", query)
    err := db.QueryRow(query, args...).Scan(&exists)
    if err != nil && err != sql.ErrNoRows {
        return false, err
    }
    return exists, nil
}


this code doesn't seem to work at all. My code always says that user hasn't applied. It is leading to duplicate entries in the table.
Userid comes from the jwt token, and job id from the query params. Where is my code wrong?
I made a func whose sole motive was to check the existence of a row in sql table but it seems to returns false everytime.
This is the response I am getting everytime.
{
    "message": "Successfully Applied!",
    "status": "Success",
    "jwt": "",
    "data": null
}

